# How to get 'vendor/doctrine/tests' in my Symfony2 project?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to unit test my orm entity repository like written in the [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html)
But I have no Doctrine\Tests\OrmTestCase class in my vendor directory. How can I get the vendor\doctrine\tests directory?

Thank you.

Comment: Notice that the page you are referring to is outdated and refers to older versions of Symfony. The current documentation can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Comment: Thank you, Carol Grandos, So, there are only functional tests for repositories, not unit.